# jQuery post to node.js -> no request.body present

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'd like to ask you for your help. I'm a bit stuck at this, no sample codes or google results could help. I don't know what's wrong.

I do a jQuery post request to my node.js server like below:

```
$.ajax({
                type        : 'POST',
                url         : "http://localhost:3000/connect-to-random-user", 
                cache       : false,
                dataType    : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                data        :  { who : myUserId },

                sucess      : function(resp) {
                    console.log("AAAAAAAAAA");
                    console.log(resp);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    console.log("requestNewPartner resp: "+JSON.stringify(resp.id));
                    if ( resp.id == "" ) {
                        console.log("No free users available");
                        setTimeout(requestNewPartner, 200);
                    }

                    var call = videoPeer.call(resp.id, stream);
                    call.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
                        $("#remoteVideo").prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
                        $("#conversationBox").append("Video Channel estabilished.");
                    });

                    chatConn = chatPeer.connect(resp.id);
                    chatConn.on('open', function() {
                        $("#conversationBox").append("Connected to a stranger");
                        $("#messageBox").val("");
                    });

                },
                error       : function (resp) {
                    console.log("ERROR requestNewPartner: "+JSON.stringify(resp));
                }
            });
```

code in node:

```
app.post('/connect-to-random-user', function (req, res) {
/*
if (req.hasOwnProperty('body')) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('data'))
        console.log("request has data field");

    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('who'))
        console.log("request has who field");
} else 
    console.log("request has no body");

console.log("asd");
appdata.users[req.body.who] = "";
console.log("Connecting "+req.who+" to random user..");

for (var id in users)
    if ( appdata.users[req.who] !== appdata.users[id]
      && appdata.users[id] == "" ) 
    {
        appdata.users[req.who] = id;
        appdata.users[id] = req.who;
        break;
    }
console.log("Connected to "+appdata.users[req.who]);*/
console.log("random-user request received");
/*res.contentType('json');
res.send({ id: appdata.users[req.who]});*/
//console.log(" content: "+req);
//console.log("stringified content: "+JSON.stringify(req));
console.log("stringified content2: "+JSON.stringify(req.params));
console.log("stringified content3: "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
res.send("WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOOOOOOOOOOOOAAAAAAA");
```

});

I get an ERROR response, and the following for the console prints:

```
random-user request received
stringified content2: {}
stringified content3: undefined
```

also tried posting stringified object as data without luck.

What can be the problem?
Any help would be really appreciated.
I know it's kind of a duplicate question, but solutions for existing ones didn't help me.
Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: This is the actual response from the server:

ERROR requestNewPartner: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOOOOOOOOOOOOAAAAAAA","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

So I get the text data, but as if it was an error. whyyyyyyy?

Comment: are you using body parser in the server?

Comment: does it matter that `sucess` should be spelled `success`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `body-parser` module.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs body parsing middleware.

Since your data type is JSON, you should be able to make use of the [Body Parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) package (available as `npm install body-parser`)

In the future, if you deal with multipart form data (such as from a standard web form), [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) may also be useful.